# Is the generator G of the keypair always the same number for all different tx messages in Bitcoin?

Tags: protocol, ecdsa

If so, what is that number and why can't you divide the public key by G to obtain the private key?

Comment: G's not publicized.

Comment: i thought the generator point G was publicly known?

Answer (score 2):

Uncompressed "G" is 0479BE667EF9DCBBAC55A06295CE870B07029BFCDB2DCE28D959F2815B16F81798483ADA7726A3C4655DA4FBFC0E1108A8FD17B448A68554199C47D08FFB10D4B8

The "04" at the beginning is simply added (for what reason I don't know).

The first 64 hex characters after the "04" supposedly represent the "x" value and the last 64 hex characters supposedly represent the "y" value.

I don't know the specifics of why it cannot be reversed (I am also seeking the answer to that question).

Answer (score 2):

No sufficiently efficient algorithm for division is known. Multiplication over a closed group is a lossy process.

For an imperfect analogy, consider multiplication over the group of 100-digit numbers where you just keep the last 100 digits of the result. Since you don't know what digits were discarded, you can't naively reverse a multiplication.

The corresponding algorithm in DSA is modular exponentiation -- `(G^X) mod n`, which is also, for practical purposes with large numbers, irreversible even if G and n are known.

Comment: Multiplication in a closed group is not lossy. It is hard to go back, but with a*G = P, if you know P and G, there will be exactly one a (modulo the order of the group) that satisfies it. It's just very hard to compute.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the "multiplication" in question is not ordinary integer multiplication, but [elliptic curve point multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication).

The whole point of working over an elliptic curve in this way is that multiplication is easy, but division is hard.